# C++: How to create enum within a function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, macros, enums

I want to simplify things, by not creating a list of enum separately, but create the enums along the function call which creates the data where i point with those enums.

I tried to make #define which would create another #define, but it didnt work:

```
int defcounter = 0;

#define make_def(enumname, somedata) \
    #define enumname defcounter \
    defcounter++; \
    func_call(somedata); \

void createstuff(){
    make_def(MY_ENUM_NAME, mydata);
    make_def(MY_OTHER_ENUMNAME, mydata);
}

void dostuff(){
    somefunc_call(MY_ENUM_NAME);
    somefunc_call(MY_OTHER_ENUMNAME);
}
```

But this will create error at the `#define enumname`:

```
error C2162: expected macro formal parameter
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: You should add `#ifdef`s around `#define enumname defcounter`. You're `#define`ing it twice.

Comment: @muntoo, where exactly did i define it twice? also, i think its best if it would make compile errors if i happen to try to define something twice.

Comment: @Rookie you're not defining anything twice, but the second #define in the macro make_def attempts to expand the token "define" and quote it, but it cannot, since it is not defined, which leads to the error I guess

Comment: @Rookie: regarding your request that the compiler generate an error (or even a warning) when something is #define'd twice, that's just not how the C preprocessor works, and it's a few decades too late to change it.

Comment: The thing is, I fail to see why you would want to create enum values at runtime. If you want to act on them in your somefunc_call, you would have to know their values beforehand, and thus you would have to have them at compile time. In this case, why not just create a normal enum? In the other case... well, an enum is just an integral type, so why not simply use an int (for example)?

Comment: @Razispio, because this way i eliminate the chances that my enum table mismatches the data order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible to create new types (classes, enums, unions, whatever) at runtime in C++. One of the major features of C++ is that it is statically typed - all types must be known at compile time.

Comment: crap... is there any other ways doing what im doing? i wouldnt want to create a string map for this...

Comment: A string map is exactly what you need to create if you want to do it at runtime.  And why not?

Comment: @Rookie Perhaps if you asked a question that did not assume a solution, we could tell you the C++ way of doing whatever it is you really want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Preprocessor commands (`#define`, `#if`, `#pragma`, `#include`, ...) cannot appear in macros / defines. The problem is, that the CPP (C-Preprocessor) seperates commands by newlines, while C and C++ are unaware of newlines. In C/C++ you can write everything on one line, for preprocessor commands, you can't.

```
#define MY_MACRO(name) \
    #define name##_macro something_cool \
    enum name{ \
      .... \
    }

// somewhere else
void myfunc(){
  MY_MACRO(myfunc_enum);
}
```

Now, at preprocessing time, those lines all get glued into one big line, thanks to the `\` backslash:

```
#define MY_MACRO(name) #define name##_macro something_cool enum name{....}
```

Now, how would that macro look at usage?

```
void myfunc(){
  #define name##_macro something_cool enum name{....};
}
```

Now, the preprocessor has to run over that `#define` again. But exactly what belongs to the `#define`, and what doesn't? For the coder it was clear when the macro was written in seperate lines, but now it isn't anymore.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is your desired output?  You need to explain what you think you might get as output from the C preprocessor.

You have scope problems and an attempt to define a macro inside the replacement text of another macro.

#### Scope

The macro `make_def()` invokes an undefined function 'func_call'.  The `createstuff()` function uses an undefined variable `mydata`.  And function `dostuff()` seems to call an undefined function `somefunc_call()` with an enum that might, perhaps, have been defined inside a separate function.

If an enumeration is defined inside one function, that enumeration is not available to code outside that function, and specifically is not available to either called functions or calling functions.  That alone limits the utility of what you seem to be attempting to do.  (Yes, the enumeration values might be implicitly converted to `int` or some similar type, but it is not really the enumeration type that is being used.)

#### Defining macros in macros

You cannot create a macro that itself contains `#define` or any other preprocessor directive in its replacement text.

If the outer macro is invoked, the expansion does not interpret the inner `#define` as being a preprocessor directive, so it almost always ends up as an error,  In context the `#` must be a stringize operator, and the word 'define' after it would have to be the name of an argument to the outer macro to have a chance of working.

```
// Does not work as intended
#define macro(define, prefix) #define another(name)   foo(prefix ## name)
macro(something, other);
```

Generates:

```
"something" another(name)  foo(othername);
```

The `_Pragma` in C99 is a partial exception to the 'a macro expansion cannot contain a preprocessor directive', but it (`_Pragma`) does not start with `#`.

Answer (score 0):

Your macro is incorrect, since you cannot use a macro to create another macro, unfortunately, as the toke # has special meaning in the expansion-list: it can either quote a macro argument, or expand another macro. One easy (albeit poorly designed) way you could do this is just to use old c-style `#define MY_ENUM_NAME value`as c macro do not respect scope, but this would not be good design. Another possibility is to pass in string arguments and hash on them, but all depends on what you want to do.